# How do we calculate likelihood in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy, statistics

I am working with two datasets and for reproducibility reasons, I am sharing the datasets [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a2iyQaG3cbBGFjyfGOlMAW3Ym0J1tL1c).

To make it clear of what I am doing - from column 2, I am reading the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Accordingly, the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

protocols = {}

types = {"data_v": "data_v.csv", "data_r": "data_r.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    diff=quotient_times
    plt.plot(diff,beta_value, ".", label=protname, color="blue")
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("quotient_times")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

This gives the following plots.

- **Data-V** has a quotient of 0.8 when the `quotient_times` is less than 3 and the quotient remains 0.5 if the `quotient_times` is
  greater than 3.
- **Data-R** has a constant `quotient` of 0.5 no matter what the value of `quotient_times`

Based on this requirement, how can we calculate the likelihood of the previous `quotient_times` and current `quotient_times` so as to differentiate `Data-V` from `Data-R`? The only place they differ is where the `quotient_times`is `<=3.01` whereas, both have the same value greater than `quotient_times`of 3. To simplify the question, **based on Data-V how likely is it that Data-R is > 0.5**?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a best fit line for both of these data sets? I don't quite understand the expected output you want from your scripts

Comment: No. My question is, if we were to classify `Data-V` and `Data-R` - how do we do it because they have the same quotient value when `quotient_times` is `>3`. So I thought if we measure the likelihood where their `quotient_times` is less than 3, then it is possible to classify them. Thanks

Comment: So you're asking, based on Data-V how likely is it that Data-R is > 0.5?

Comment: Hi Prune, I think I have included everything to make it reproducible. I am sorry, I had to share the datasets on Google Drive because that's the only I could do. If there is anything missing, i would love to include it

Comment: @Reedinationer, Exactly and thank you so much for understanding my question.

Comment: Well to me it looks like the data sets are not correlated to each other (i.e. a change in one does not change the other). Perhaps if Data-V changed at all when Data-R changed you could relate them. I think in this case it would be best to just analyze Data-R in a manner like (`probability R > 0.5` / `occurences of R`) to get a percentage of how often R > 0.5

Comment: @Reedinationer, that also could be an option. I tried a couple of approaches but I got stuck. Could you try that and post an answer when you get a chance? Thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just asking for the probability that Data-V > 0.5 I would find its independent probability. As I have commented, I don't think there is a correlation between the data because Data-V has a spike, while Data-R does not react at all.

```
import numpy as np

types = {"data_v": "data_v.csv"} # only considering data-V

for protname, fname in types.items(): # your code to load the data
    col_time, col_window = np.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1]  # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds] / trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    # Now we'll go through the data for quotients and find how many meet the > 0.5 criteria
    count = 0
    for quot in quotient:
        if quot > 0.5:
            count += 1

    probability = float(count) / len(quotient) # Calculate a float of occurrences / chances to occur
    print(probability)
```

Outputs

> 0.0625

So there is a 6.25% chance that Data-V will be above 0.5 when it is considered independent of Data-V

**UPDATE**

If you would like to only consider when quotient_times are less than 3:

```
import numpy as np

types = {"data_v": "data_v.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time, col_window = np.loadtxt(fname, delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1]  # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds] / trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    occurrence_count = 0
    possibility_count = 0
    for index in range(len(quotient)):
        if quotient_times[index] < 3:
            possibility_count += 1
            if quotient[index] > 0.5:
                occurrence_count += 1

    probability = float(occurrence_count) / possibility_count
    print(probability)
```

Outputs

> 1.0

So 100% of the data set where `quotient_times` is less than 3 also has a `quotient` value greater than 0.5. Again this only considers Data-V

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. Can we do that ONLY when the `quotient_times` is less than 3.1? If we consider only Data-V, shouldn't the probability that it will be above 0.5 is very high?

Comment: @Brown I added an update where only quotient times less than 3 are considered. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes and thank you so much. It would cool if we could consider multiple data (like Data-V and Data-R) as I included in the question but I will mark your answer as accepted for your help and time. You are awesome! Here is the idea i had on mind: 1) take `quotient_times` t 2) store the `quotient` values for both data (Data-R and Data-V) - save the previous value and the current value 3) calculate the likelihood 4) choose the higher likelihood.

Comment: @Brown Thanks! There are statistics that can compare them but I don't remember them from 7 or so years ago. I think the data sets would have to change in similar ways though for those algorithms to work